# Variable as jQuery selector focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JavaScript to copy a specific div from a page into a new page.  I need to remove the ID attributes for each table in the new page.

It seems that since I'm copying content from the first page, I can filter out the IDs from the string before it is written to the second page.  Can jQuery take a variable as its 'focus'?  Instead of manipulating the entire DOM, manipulate a particular string?

I have a non-working version of what I'm talking about:

```
var currentContent =  window.open('','currentContentWindow');
var htmlToCopy = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>' + window.frames[0].document.getElementById('PageContentPane').innerHTML + '</body></html>';

        $("table", htmlToCopy).removeAttr('id');

        currentContent.document.open();
        currentContent.document.write(htmlToCopy);
        currentContent.document.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a jQuery object by calling `$(html)`, manipulate it, then get the HTML back by calling `html()`.

For example:

```
var currentContent =  window.open('','currentContentWindow');
var htmlToCopy = '<html><head><title></title></head><body>' + window.frames[0].document.getElementById('PageContentPane').innerHTML + '</body></html>';

var newStructure = $("<div>" + htmlToCopy + "</div>");
newStructure.find("table").removeAttr('id');

currentContent.document.open();
currentContent.document.write(newElements.html());
```

The `<div>` element allows me to get its *inner* HTML and get the HTML you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Who not just remove `ID=` as a string and forget DOM manipulation all together?

Comment: _Please, **no**._  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Who says you even need to use REGEX for this. Just swap "ID=" with some meaningless attribute tag like "XX=".

Answer (score 0):

First make the string a jQuery object, then work with it:

```
htmlToCopy = $(htmlToCopy).find("table").removeAttr('id').end().html();
```